# script not running in templateurl

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, highcharts

This is my angular js file

test.js file:

```
var app = angular.module("angleapp", [])
.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.test = "hi all"
}])
.directive('programlisting', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
        },
        templateUrl: '/directives/test.html'
    };
});
```

test.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            alert("stop");
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        hi how are you
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my index file:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
        <script src="/directives/test.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body data-ng-app="angleapp"> 
        <div class="main" ng-controller="MainController">
            <programlisting></programlisting>
        </div>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Now when I try to run this

```
hi how are you
```

is coming in the output. but the alert window does not pop-op where i am i going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `script` tags are not executed by browser automatically when injected with `innerHTML` (what happens in case of `templateUrl`). Normally this tags are evaluated programmatically (`eval`). jQuery does it but jqLite (internal jQuery-like implementation of Angular) does not.

In your case the fix is simple, move jquery script tag *before* angular, then Angular will use jQuery for DOM manipulations:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Also, you need to clean up your `test.html` template, leave only body content. This is how `test.html` should look:

```html
hi how are you

<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("stop");
</script>
```

And finally, I don't know why you need to have script tag inside of partial template, but in most cases this is bad idea, and there are better approaches.

Comment: thnx a ton.. had been stuck here more than an hour. btw waht are the better approaches instead of using script tag inside partial templates?

Comment: You could look at the link attribute of the directive tag

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. Why do you need script inside template? But in your case since you have custom directive, you should use link function of the directive. This is a code to be executed once template is rendered and connected to scope. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-link-

Comment: Script tag not executed since html5. Refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

Answer (score 1):

In partials html page(test.html), No need to write doctype, head and body tags. Just write your html elements and script. It should work.

Comment: already tried that but not workin i mean the alert window does not show up

Comment: Can you create JS fiddle?