# AngularJS: Script tag not working in ng-include

Tags: angularjs, dom

I have a file index.html with the following code:

```
<div ng-include="'fragment-1.html'"></div>
```

The code of fragment-1.html:

```
<b>Inside Fragment 1</b>
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Inside Fragment 1");
</script>
```

When I load index.html into the browser, output is:

**Inside Fragment 1**

The DOM has the `<script>` tags but the alert is not shown.

**My hypothesis:**

Because the DOM loads first along with the Angular modules and then Angular checks and binds the data(in this case, fragment-1.html file content) to the view(index.html), it just adds the elements of fragment-1.html in DOM. To execute the JS inside fragment-1.html, we should create a hack for it. Am I right in this explanation? Or is there something else that I may be missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can i load javascript file along with ng-include template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20087274/how-can-i-load-javascript-file-along-with-ng-include-template)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to load jQuery before loading Angular. The explanation is in the link specified above. Explanation: [script not running in templateurl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32048046/script-not-running-in-templateurl)

To include another partial HTML file in your parent HTML file, one can also use Angular directives, depending on the situation. See this answer for when to use ng-include and when to use directives: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24172025/3132646

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to hack. Angular gives you a neat and simple solution to what you want to achieve with your code.

Controller

```
.controller('fragmentOneCtrl', function ($scope) {
    alert('"Inside Fragment 1"');
})
```

View

```
<div ng-repeat="go in ['go', 'gogo']" ng-include="'includeThis'">

</div>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="includeThis">
    <div ng-controller="fragmentOneCtrl">

    </div>
</script>
```

Comment: This works perfectly when the code is in index.html itself. I want to include a separate file fragment-1.html whose javascript code should run when it is included in index.html.

Comment: Ok but is it not an exact use case for directive?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to directives. Still learning Angular. Was still unable to execute JS inside fragment-1.html using directives. Found my answer here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32048046/script-not-running-in-templateurl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32048046/script-not-running-in-templateurl)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `$sce.trustAsHtml` before injecting the resource in html